# MY sql query not working fully

Tags: php, mysql

I am using to add data into DB. First i get the values from post and then insert it into table. The problem is that there are total 7 values but only 5 values added and 2 of them not inserted into the table. Here is my code

```
if( 'POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] && !empty( $_POST['action'] )) {
        $degree_title = $_POST['degree_title'];
        $degree_year = $_POST['degree_year'];
        $uni_name = $_POST['uni_name'];
        $degree_level = $_POST['degree_level'];
        $major_sub = $_POST['major_sub'];



        $run = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `career_fourudb`.`tffeck_employee_edu` (`id`, `employee_id`, `degree`, `year`, `degree_level`, `major_degree`, `uni`) 
        VALUES (NULL, $eme_uid, $degree_title, $degree_year, $degree_level, $major_sub, $uni_name)");


    }
```

I echo the all values and all values are coming so why they all not inserted into table any idea. Thank

Comment: strings in values have to be in '$degree_title'

Comment: GET MODERN: Learn to use MySQLi or PDO with prepared statements and bind variables, then you wouldn't have this problem - you'd have hoped that any coding related to educational establishments would be using practises from this century, not last century

Comment: @MarkBaker +1, the problem is there are to many "bad" wanna-be howtos out there....

Comment: If you're just learning PHP, then I suggest reading http://www.phptherightway.com/#databases

Comment: How does your html-form look like?

Comment: @Rufinus i use '$degree_title', but it still not insert it, and all other values is inserted accept degree_title and major_sub.

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld what the heck does anything have to do with the form???? your username seems to be a joke... a bad one i may add..

Comment: use the line i posted below in my answer.. if it doesn work write a comment with the error.

Comment: @Rufinus - I don't know what I've done to you, but you seem a little offensive. But you're right, OP said all the values are set.

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld sorry but with that nickname you must get used to a litte "trash talk"

Comment: @Rufinus - no actually you're the first to do some "trash-talk" :-)

Comment: @Rufinus actually there is no error because query insert 5 values and not all 7 values.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
$run = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `career_fourudb`.`tffeck_employee_edu` (`id`, `employee_id`, `degree`, `year`, `degree_level`, `major_degree`, `uni`) 
    VALUES (NULL, '$eme_uid', '$degree_title', '$degree_year', '$degree_level', '$major_sub', '$uni_name')");
```

and i would highly recommend:

1) dont use mysql_ its deprecated, use mysqli_*

2) sanitze ALL values in _POST befor using in SQL statements.

Comment: i am new in php so i really don' get you who to use it.

Comment: search for "php sanitize user values" and take a good look at the link form Mark Baker http://phptherightway.com

Comment: i use mysqli and sanitze but it still have same problem. Inserting only 5 values not all 7 values.

Comment: are you sure the missing 2 values are filled? `var_dump($_POST)` to verify

Comment: yes i am sure the two missing values are filled. I also verify the name of field each and every thing, Its never happen with be before i really very confuse where i missing

Answer (score 0):

if `id` is autoincrement then you dont need to insert  it.

try this

```
     $run = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `career_fourudb`.`tffeck_employee_edu` (`employee_id`, `degree`, `year`, `degree_level`, `major_degree`, `uni`) 
    VALUES ($eme_uid, $degree_title, $degree_year, $degree_level, $major_sub, $uni_name)");
```

Comment: Won't help with string fields like $degree_title

Comment: @echo_me its not working, and it not make any sence that you remove the id or not. It work for both, but the main problem is why only 5 values inserted,

Comment: i guess `$eme_uid` didnt inserted koz i dont see you are defining it.

Comment: it is inserted because i get the values from session. the two values which is not inserted are degree_title and major_sub

Comment: check your session_start(). i can help without looking your code

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that `$degree_title` and `$uni_name` doesn't get inserted because they are varchars. In that case you will have to put quotes around these values.

Mysql is kind of "forgiving" in the sence that it does not throw an error when using incorrect types in the sql-statement in relation to the actual type of the column.

**Try:**

```
$run = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `career_fourudb`.`tffeck_employee_edu` (`id`, `employee_id`, `degree`, `year`, `degree_level`, `major_degree`, `uni`)
      VALUES (NULL, $eme_uid, '$degree_title', $degree_year, $degree_level, $major_sub, '$uni_name')");
```

As mentioned before id doesn't have to be included (if id-column is autoincremental) in the insert-statement, and you should really learn mysqli or PDO.